# Joomla2.5 Cannot translate K2 extra fields values with joomfish

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, translation, joomla-k2, joomfish

I am working on a multilingual joomla 2.5 website and I am using K2 articles.
In K2 I have an extra field which is a drop down list.
When I am using joomfish in order to translate it I can only translate the field's label.
Is there a way to translate the list's values?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try -

https://code.google.com/p/getk2/issues/detail?id=491

This is a core hack so you will have to redo it every time you upgrade K2 until they get it added to the extension.

Comment: not working! k2 and joomfish integration for extra field translation does not seem to work!

Answer (score 1):

I use [FaLang](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/18210) to translate k2 items and extra fields names. To translate extra fields values I use the [Easy Language](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/19439) plugin and it works perfectly.